# Looking for a wxPython widget

Tags: wxpython

I'm creating a dialogue in wxPython and need to have my users put data in a specific order. It should look something like this:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/R6Z4slj.jpg]

Sorry for the crude drawing, for the life of me I can't seem to find this anywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

wx python has one of those its called an items picker.
I'm not sure what version it was introduced in but its in wxpython version 2.9.4.0, you'll find it in wx.lib.itemspicker

If its not in your version here is the code from the wx.lib

```
'''
Created on Oct 3, 2010

@authors: Daphna Rosenbom,Gitty Zinger,Moshe Cohavi and Yoav Glazner
The widget is contributed by NDS ltd under the same license as wxPython

items_picker.ItemsPicker:
  - Displays available items to choose from,</LI>
  - Selection is done by the Add button or Double Click,</LI>
  - De-Selection is done by the Remove button or Double Click,</LI>

  Derived from wxPanel
'''
import wx
__version__ = 0.1

IP_DEFAULT_STYLE = 0
IP_SORT_CHOICES = 1
IP_SORT_SELECTED = 2
IP_REMOVE_FROM_CHOICES = 4


wxEVT_IP_SELECTION_CHANGED = wx.NewEventType()
EVT_IP_SELECTION_CHANGED = wx.PyEventBinder(wxEVT_IP_SELECTION_CHANGED, 1)
LB_STYLE = wx.LB_EXTENDED|wx.LB_HSCROLL


class IpSelectionChanged(wx.PyCommandEvent):
    def __init__(self, id, items, object = None):
        wx.PyCommandEvent.__init__(self, wxEVT_IP_SELECTION_CHANGED, id)
        self.__items = items
        self.SetEventObject(object)

    def GetItems(self):
        return self.__items


class ItemsPicker(wx.Panel):
    '''
    ItemsPicker is a widget that allows the user to form a set of picked
    items out of a given list
    '''
    def __init__(self, parent, id=wx.ID_ANY, choices = [],
                 label = '', selectedLabel = '',
                 ipStyle = IP_DEFAULT_STYLE,
                 *args, **kw):
        '''
        ItemsPicker(parent, choices = [], label = '', selectedLabel = '',
                    ipStyle = IP_DEFAULT_STYLE)
        '''
        wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id, *args, **kw)
        self._ipStyle = ipStyle
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
        sizer.Add(self._CreateSourceList(choices, label), 1,
                   wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self._CreateButtons(), 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER|wx.ALL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self._CreateDestList(selectedLabel), 1,
                   wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        self.SetSizer(sizer)


    def SetItems(self, items):
        '''SetItems(self, items)=> None
        items - Sequence of strings that the user can pick from''' 
        return self._source.SetItems(items)    


    def GetItems(self): 
        '''GetItems(self)=> items
        returns list of strings that the user can pick from''' 
        return self._source.GetItems()


    Items = property(fget = GetItems,
                     fset = SetItems,
                     doc = 'See GetItems/SetItems')


    def GetSelections(self):
        '''GetSelections(self)=>items
        returns list of strings that were selected
        ''' 
        return self._dest.GetItems()


    def SetSelections(self, items): 
        '''SetSelections(self, items)=>None
        items - Sequence of strings to be selected
        The items are displayed in the selection part of the widget'''
        assert len(items)==len(set(items)),"duplicate items are not allowed"
        if items != self._dest.GetItems():
            self._dest.SetItems(items)
            self._FireIpSelectionChanged()


    Selections = property(fget = GetSelections,
                     fset = SetSelections,
                     doc = 'See GetSelections/SetSelections')


    def _CreateButtons(self):
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.bAdd = wx.Button(self, -1, label = 'Add ->')
        self.bAdd.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._OnAdd)
        self.bRemove = wx.Button(self, -1, label = '<- Remove')
        self.bRemove.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self._OnRemove)
        sizer.Add(self.bAdd, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL|wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL, 5)
        sizer.Add(self.bRemove, 0, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        return sizer


    def _set_add_button_label(self, label=None):
        if label is None:
            return
        self.bAdd.SetLabel(label)

    add_button_label = property(fset = _set_add_button_label, fget = lambda x:x)


    def _set_remove_button_label(self, label=None):
        if label is None:
            return
        self.bRemove.SetLabel(label)

    remove_button_label = property(fset = _set_remove_button_label, fget = lambda x:x)


    def _OnAdd(self, e):
        if self._ipStyle & IP_REMOVE_FROM_CHOICES:
            self._MoveItems(self._source,self._dest)
        else:
            self._AddSelectedItems()

    def _MoveItems(self,source,dest):
        selections = source.GetSelections()
        selectedItems = map(source.GetString, selections)
        dest.SetItems(dest.GetItems() + selectedItems)
        selections = set(selections)
        source.SetItems([item for i, item in enumerate(source.GetItems())\
                      if i not in selections])
        self._FireIpSelectionChanged()

    def _AddSelectedItems(self):
        newItems = map(self._source.GetString, self._source.GetSelections())
        items = self._dest.GetItems()
        oldItems = set(items)
        for newItem in newItems:
            if newItem not in oldItems:
                items.append(newItem)    
        self.SetSelections(items)


    def _FireIpSelectionChanged(self):
            self.GetEventHandler().ProcessEvent(
                        IpSelectionChanged(self.GetId(), 
                                            self._dest.GetItems(),
                                             self ))


    def _OnRemove(self, e):
        if self._ipStyle & IP_REMOVE_FROM_CHOICES:
            self._MoveItems(self._dest, self._source)
        else:
            self._RemoveSelected()

    def _RemoveSelected(self):
        selections = self._dest.GetSelections()
        if selections:
            allItems = self._dest.GetItems()
            items = [item for i, item in enumerate(allItems)\
                      if i not in selections]
            self.SetSelections(items)
            self._FireIpSelectionChanged()


    def _CreateSourceList(self, items, label):
        style = LB_STYLE
        if self._ipStyle & IP_SORT_CHOICES:
            style |= wx.LB_SORT
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        if label:
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label = label), 0,
                       wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self._source = wx.ListBox(self, -1, style = style)
        self._source.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK, self._OnDClick)
        self._source.SetItems(items)
        sizer.Add(self._source, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        return sizer


    def _CreateDestList(self, label):
        style = LB_STYLE
        if self._ipStyle & IP_SORT_SELECTED:
            style |= wx.LB_SORT
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        if label:
            sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(self, label = label), 0,
                       wx.ALIGN_LEFT|wx.ALL, 5)
        self._dest = wx.ListBox(self, -1, style = style)
        self._dest.Bind(wx.EVT_LISTBOX_DCLICK,  self._OnDClick) 
        sizer.Add(self._dest, 1, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, 5)
        return sizer


    def _OnDClick(self, e):
        lb = e.GetEventObject()
        selections = lb.GetSelections()
        if len(selections) != 1:
            return #DCLICK only works on one item
        if e.GetSelection() != selections[0]:
            #this can happen using ^DCLICK when two items are selected
            return
        if lb  == self._source: 
            self._OnAdd(e)
        else:
            self._OnRemove(e)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    test = wx.PySimpleApp(0)
    frame = wx.Frame(None, -1)
    d = wx.Dialog(frame, style = wx.RESIZE_BORDER|wx.DEFAULT_DIALOG_STYLE)

    d.sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
    d.sizer.Add(wx.StaticText(d, -1, label = 'Example of the ItemsPicker'),
                 0, wx.ALL, 10)
    ip = ItemsPicker(d, -1, ['pop', 'cool', 'lame'],
                      'Stuff:', 'Selected stuff:',IP_SORT_SELECTED|IP_SORT_CHOICES|IP_REMOVE_FROM_CHOICES)
    ip.add_button_label = u'left -> right'
    ip.remove_button_label = u'right -> left'
    d.sizer.Add(ip, 1, wx.EXPAND, 1)
    d.SetSizer(d.sizer)
    test.SetTopWindow(frame)
    def callback(e):
        print 'selected items', e.GetItems()
    d.Bind(EVT_IP_SELECTION_CHANGED, callback)
    d.ShowModal()
    d.Destroy()
    frame.Close()
```